# Adding checked checkboxes based on items selected in shopping cart

Tags: php, checkbox, shopping-cart, checkout

I have a shopping cart where people can add items on different pages.

Through all the pages, you can add items to the cart by clicking a button on a product page.

When people go to the "checkout" page, there will be checkboxes for all items, and those selected in the shopping cart should be "checked". This way they can send me the mail and I know which ones they have selected.

The only thing I could get working was that all items selected showed a checked checkbox. But I want to have checkboxes of all items and only those selected being checked so people can add items when at the checkout page.

I hope someone can help me, I'm not asking for full scripts, but what would be the best way to achieve it?

When it's hard to understand, this explains it better: What I want is a check box for each item with those in the shopping cart already checked.

Thanks

Comment: How do you store products in shopping cart SESSION or in DATABSE ?

Comment: In a SESSION, I don't know if that's the best option tho
If you want I can give you all the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this : (This may not be the exact code you needed.)

```
<?php
foreach($products as $product){
$pid  = $product['pid'];
?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>" <?php if(in_array($pid,$_SESSION['cart'])){ ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> /> Product name
<?php } ?>
```

It checks whether the `$pid` exists in `SESSION`, If exists check the checkbox

Comment: `$products` this is your product array, which contains all the products, ie data fetched from database.

Comment: Ok, I think it will work but I can't find the array ($products), i'm not very good in php yet but I think I almost got it working, but i'm a little stuck with the foreach line now